# Catch cURL error is not working properly. does not give error if data is not received

Tags: php, curl

I have this cURL code. It is not throwing error if no data received. how should I put the check if any data received?

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.serverurl.com/data');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);               
$fh = @fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === null || $result == FALSE || $result == '') {
    return false;
} else {
   echo 'success';
   fclose($fh);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Put `unlink('myfile.txt')` in the `if` scope

Comment: If no data is received, it will still report it as success, since it will probably still be a "200" or "204" HTTP Status Code.

Comment: what should be done? I am also checking with this condition with $result = curl_exec($ch)... if ($result == null) .  but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Checks the response code and if response is empty or not.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.serverurl.com/data');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);               

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

if ($httpCode === 200) {
    if (empty($response)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        file_put_contents('myfile.txt', $response);
        return true;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

And if response is an empty JSON Array or Object

```
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

if (preg_match("/json/i", $contentType)) { $response = json_decode($response, true); }
```

So...

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

if ($httpCode === 200) {
    if (preg_match("/json/i", $contentType)) { $response = json_decode($response, true); }
    if (empty($response)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        file_put_contents('myfile.txt', $response);
        return true;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I m getting 301 not 200

Comment: Which means the address your accessing, is moved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: so atleast it should check the empty response condition but it is not even checking that. I have removed the Code condition and just checked the empty condition with empty() === null, == " "... everything. but its not throwing error and file is empty

Comment: I am checking the condition with $response = curl_exec($ch) which will offcourse not null but 1. How do I check it curl received some data or no?

Comment: `if (empty($response)) {` checks if there is data or not. depending on what it returns, you might want to tweak that, like if its JSON, it will probably return a empty array or object, if there is no "data".

Comment: can you write by what do you mean

Comment: I mean how do you check with JSON?

Comment: Edited, with JSON response.

Comment: Content type is not JSON. Its text

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This code just little modification to your code
    <?php 
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.serverurl234.com/data');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);               
    $fh = @fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === null || $result == FALSE || $result == '') {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        return false;
    } else {
       echo 'success';
       fclose($fh);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>

[![Output][1]][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx4z8.png
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); this line has been edited

Comment: whats the difference if I echo it or not?

Comment: if there is no data is passed from the url it will display an error(i.e Curl error )

Comment: i have attached output image i got if url is wrong & data is not passed check please

Comment: try to give url which is not having any data like what i have given

Comment: It works fine if URL is completely wrong. try with a redirected URL

Comment: it means that earlier what url you passed was having some data sir

Comment: thts the problem :(

Comment: hence it is creating myfile.txt and writing something into it and showing success in your case

Comment: Its not writing anything to it. File is blank.

Comment: file is blank when you have wrong url, now give correct url and check

Comment: Its catching any all error other than a redirected URLs

Comment: <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=serverurl&amp;e=com">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>  This is what written into myfile.txt

Comment: mine is complete empty

Comment: "edit very first line to this and execute and then check" => $url='http://www.serverurl.com/data'  $ch = curl_init($url )

Comment: Its the same. You put url in or out doesnt make any difference

Comment: use very first line of code you have posted in the question as it is and check sir

Comment: I checked. No result :(